# Action in controller with two parameters - how to set up route and controller?

Tags: vb.net, http, get, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this controller:

```
 Public Class UsersController
    Inherits ApiController
    Public reportsjsonfilepath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\reports.json"
    <HttpGet>
    <Route("")>
    Public Function Index() As HttpResponseMessage
        Log.Information("Main index requested at {0}", DateTime.Now)
        Dim response As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        response.Append("Index requested at: " & DateTime.Now)
        response.Append("<br>")
        response.Append("Hello, this is a test WebApi server!")
        Dim raspuns = String.Join("/n", response.ToString)
        Dim raspunsindex = Request.CreateResponse(Of String)(HttpStatusCode.OK, raspuns)
        raspunsindex.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")
        Return raspunsindex
    End Function
    <HttpGet>
    <Route("users")>
    Public Function Users() As HttpResponseMessage
        Log.Information("Users index requested at {0}", DateTime.Now)
        Dim response As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim dictionarusers As IDictionary(Of String, String) = GetUsersList()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dictionarusers
            i = i + 1
            response.Append(i)
            response.Append(" - ")
            response.Append(entry.Value)
            response.Append("<br>")
        Next
        Dim raspuns = Request.CreateResponse(Of String)(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.ToString)
        raspuns.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")
        Return raspuns
    End Function
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function GetQlikLink(username As String, reportId As Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
        QlikLink.GetLink(username, reportId)
    End Function
End Class
```

The routes are set up like this:

```
    Public Module RoutesConfig
            <Extension()>
            Sub MapDefinedRoutes(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="Relevance", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}", defaults:=New With {
                    .id = RouteParameter.[Optional]
                })
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("QlikLink", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", New With {
    .id = RouteParameter.[Optional]
}) 

    End Sub
    End Module
```

Now, when I go `http://localhost:9000/relevance`, the index kicks in OK. Same for `http://localhost:9000/relevance/users`. But how one must set-up the action and the route to get something by getting the params from the request? How the parameters are sent: ?username=somestring&?id=2? I am talking about function `GetQlikLink`, the last one from the `Controller`.

Any hint will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For actions where the parameters are different to those defined in the routing configuration, then the query string keys should be the same as the function parameter names.

```
http://..../GetQlikLink?username=xyz&reportId=1234
```

I would recommend reading up about the different types of routing.
The config which you have shown looks like convention based routing.
However, you also appear to be adding routing attributes to your action methods.

Convention based routing lets you define route *templates*, and the pattern of things like `{controller}` and `{action}` must match the names of the controller and actions.

[Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

The other articles in this section also describe attribute routing.